# Upgrading home network: multiple floors and VLANs

Tags: networking, vlan

I'm trying to design a new network for my house, which is spread across 4 floors. I've been thinking about my requirements and I tried to write down

**Requirements**

*Security Cameras*

- security cameras should not have internet access;
- security cameras must access the network video recorder (NVR);
- the NVR should be able to access a remote mail server to send email notifications in case of security incidents
- a special security camera will require internet access *and* NVR access; **Update**: *special* here means that the camera allows for 2-way audio communication over the Internet, e.g. talking to the person in front of the camera.
- I should be able to access the NVR (even ethernet only is fine);

*Heating System*

- thermostat should not have internet access;
- thermostatic valves should not have internet access;
- the family should be able to access the heating system (wifi);

*Home office*

- 2 PCs on ethernet (VLAN 4)
- 1 PC on Wifi
- printer
- NAS

*Other misc devices*

- Smart TVs with internet access;
- Gaming systems with internet access;

*Wifi network coverage*

- Guest access (fully isolated network)
- Family access (can access heating system and NAS)

**Rough network structure**

[image: ASCII Network Diagram]

**Doubts and questions**

- I'm thinking of the following VLANs:

  2. cameras
  3. special camera
  4. NVR
  5. Guest
  6. heating
  7. office
  8. family safe (for internal wifi)
  9. family unsafe (gamign systems, tv, etc.)

Is this breakdown reasonable? It's unclear to me if that would satisfy all my requirements. For example, would I be able to configure the network so that I can access the NVR (VLAN 4) and the special camera (VLAN 3) from VLAN 8 or 7?

- How intensive is inter-VLAN routing? I'm assuming this can be handled by the Edge Router (powered by dd-wrt).
- The "special camera" is a potential security risk... right? Is it enough for it to be in its own VLAN?
- I'm considering using CAT6A for all my connections and 1Gigabit Ethernet for the trunking ports between the switches. Would another cable category or trunking speed (10Gigabit Ethernet?) be more appropriate *for connecting the switches*? I'm not initially planning for using any 10G network device. This might change in the future for the NAS.
- Is there any specific *feature* I should look for in the switch I'm going to buy?
- Do I need a DHCP server for each VLAN for having dynamic assignment? Can a single router handle the addressing for all the VLANs?

Pardon me for the length of the question (and sub-questions :D). I hope this isn't OT: looks fitting giving the list of topics [here](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really big project with many choices.

> How intensive is inter-VLAN routing? I'm assuming this can be handled by the Edge Router (powered by dd-wrt).

security camera -> NVR traffic can reach 2 - 7  Mbit/s per camera depends on camera brand and recording modes.

**UPD.** It can kneel down generic WRT router. WRT1900ACS is 2 cores 1.6 Ghz CPU. And declare performance 1900 Mbps

> The "special camera" is a potential security risk... right? Is it enough for it to be in its own VLAN?

Depends on what *special* in it.

> I'm considering using CAT6A for all my connections and 1Gigabit Ethernet for the trunking ports between the switches. Would another cable category or trunking speed (10Gigabit Ethernet?) be more appropriate?

10G eqyipment cost more. So it more budget question.

You plan to use 10G devices (NAS, PC ...)?

When hidden in-wall wiring is used and cable replacment is hard. It good idea to use cable class which allow link speed upgrade in future when needed.

> Do I need a DHCP server for each VLAN for having dynamic assignment? Can a single router handle the addressing for all the VLANs?

With full isolated VLANs yes.

But many managed switches support some kind of Port Isolation/Leakage.

For example: NVR , router and cameras in one VLAN but in different isolation groups, so any camera can communicate only with NVR but not with router or oter cmeras.

**PS.**

One Wi-Fi AP may be not enough for 4 floors house. So Plan VLANs for Guest Wi-Fi and Family Wi-Fi

When more complex configuration You choose, then more resources to implement, maintain and troubleshoot required. Be Wise. Look from point of view of *threat scenarios*.

**UPD2.**
To keep wiring quality keep this [UTP CABLING INSTALLATION PRACTICES](https://www.etcconnect.com/Support/Articles/Unshielded-Twisted-Pair-Cabling-Installation-Practices.aspx)

> - To avoid stretching, pulling tension should not exceed 110N (25 lb ƒ ) for 4-pair cables.
> - Installed bend radii shall not exceed:
>
>   - 4 times the cable diameter for horizontal UTP cables.
>   - 10 times the cable diameter for multi-pair backbone UTP cables.
> - Avoid cable stress, as caused by:
>
>   - cable twist during pulling or installation
>   - tension in suspended cable runs
>   - tightly cinched cable ties or staples
>   - tight bend radii

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, this is useful! I've updated my question to provide more details. The camera is "special" as it allows 2-way audio/video to communicate with the person in front of it. I'm not initially planning to use 10G devices, but that might change for the NAS. Just to be a bit more precise: my doubt is if the connection between the switches needed to be 10G rather than 1G. Thanks for the pointers on the APs and the cable category: is CAT6A enough for future upgrades? Looks like they support 10G for lengths up to 55m [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable#cite_note-8).

Comment: 'CAT6A enough for future upgrades?' It depend on budget, but 10x reserve (1G vs 10G) look promising.

Comment: About 10G at home now. 1Gb/s is about 85MB/s. Rare HDD (exceps SSD) make more, so Your NAS most probably limited in 70 - 80 MB/s (except large 6+ hdd installations) real file performance. Home load have low concurency (1-3 concurent sessions) with rare traffic burst (opening a media file, file transfer, or movie FF). Movie watch make average load in 1 - 10 Mbps.

Comment: Thank you Mikhail! I've accepted your answer as it goes through all the things I needed and it cleared my mind :) One thing: any thought about the *special camera* security implications?

Comment: I don't see something special in *special* camera, except it accessible from Internet.

Answer (score 0):

VLANS are inherently segregated and i would recommend keeping them as segregated as possible, that is minimize/eliminate any "inter VLAN" routing.  In the end, this really should leave you mostly solving how to share a single internet connection across all the VLANs.

Physically, all your wires can all come into a single patch panel for ease of management.  Then, you can run VLANs off a managed switch if you want to simplify your equipment.

But you don't have to run VLANs, you can just run separate LANs as well with separate switches per LAN. VLANs would help alot with combing your equipment failure modes so you don't have to manage all the other switches separately but it is not required.

From there, it just depends on how you want to manage things.  Ultimate, complete segregation is the best.  Or you might combine the unsafe internet stuff, (3,5 &9), the safe internet stuff (7,8) and non internet stuff (2,4 &6) in a way that makes sense.  Either way you can bring the networks to a very configurable router or linux box to manage the cross network routing. Or, or, or...

There are a plethora of ways to configure this all because you have options at each layer of the OSI model.  Go through the OSI layering and nail down your desired options at each layer and implement them.   What *YOU* implement will depend on *YOUR* use case, *YOUR* needs, *YOUR* budget, etc.

*This really is more of a long winded comment, but didn't have enough room in a comment and as such I would expect this question to get closed for being too broad.*

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! As for the last part, while I understand that the first question might be broader than expected, I think the remaining points are narrow enough for this to be left open.